# What does this notation $J = 11^T ∈ M_n(R)$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, transpose

I am solving some problems in Matrices and I came across this problem, I don't want the solution. I am having a little difficulty in understanding the notation given in the problem. Here is the problem,

Let $J = 11^T ∈ M_n(R)$. Then each entry of $J$ equals $1$. Which among these is the incorrect option?

And he gave some options. Can somebody explain what does the question mean? I don't understand what is this $11^T$ and what is $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$?

If writing down the options can help, I can add those options in the question.

Comment: $1$ is here a column vector $(1,\ldots,1)$. So writing $11^T$ gives a matrix $J$ with every coefficient $1$.

Comment: Blackboard bold \mathbb like $\mathbb M_n (\mathbb R)$? Then it probably means the set of $n\times n$ matrices with real coefficients.

Comment: How can we write that $M_n(R)$ like you have written in your comment? Yes in the question it is there like the one you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @Chrystomath So $11^T$ means transpose of two column vectors that are written side by side? or is it something else? Can you explain with an example what the author of the question wants to say?

Comment: So is it product of two matrices one is column matrix of $n*1$ and other is transpose of column matrix i.e., $1*n$? So the resulting matrix is of size $n*n$? Also all the entries of column vector is $1$ or can they be anything else?

Comment: $$J=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\ \vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\1&1&\cdots&1\\ \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yeah, Now understood! Thank you! Where can I learn formatting tips like how you have written matrices if I want to add them in any question?

Comment: @NaniBabu - See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @NaniBabu If you left-click on any expression on this site, you will get a menu from which you can display the MathJax code. So if you see something interesting, click on it.

Comment: I can see the confusion here. It probably would have been better if the author wrote something like $\mathbf{1}(\mathbf{1})^{\mathrm{T}}\in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context, it can be inferred that $1$ is the $n\times 1$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$, i.e.
$$ 1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ \vdots\\ 1\end{pmatrix}. $$
Given a matrix $A$, the matrix $A^T$ denotes the transpose of that matrix.  That is, if $a_{ij}$ denotes the entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of $A$, then the value in the $i$-th column and $j$-th row of $A^T$ is $a_{ij}$, i.e.
$$ (a^T)_{ji} = a_{ij}. $$
Hence
$$ 1^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dotsb & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Again assuming that $1$ is of length $n$, it therefore follows that
$$ J
= 11^T
= \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ \vdots\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dotsb & 1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dotsb & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \dotsb & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \dotsb & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
i.e. the $n\times n$ matrix consisting entirely of $1$s.

Finally, (again inferring from context, though this notation is reasonably standard) $\mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries.  For example, $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ consists of all matrices of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \end{pmatrix}$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all real numbers.

---

On a slightly different topic, I feel like the notation in this problem was written to confound, rather than illuminate (though, as I said, we can infer the correct meaning from context).  I might have preferred to write something like

> Let $\mathbb{1}_n$ denote the $n\times 1$ matrix
> $$ \mathbb{1}_n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{pmatrix}. $$
> Then $J = \mathbb{1}_n \cdot \mathbb{1}_n^T \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the $n\times n$ matrix in which every entry is $1$.

I think that it vastly improves readability to use a different font for this $\mathbb{1}_n$ matrix, and to explicitly indicate its size in the notation.